# Floating UI - is it possible to avoid the popper being clipped by overflow:hidden on the parent?

Tags: floating-ui

I'm trying to create a dropdown element with floating-ui. My problem is that when the  floating ui element is within a parent that has overflow: hidden/auto/scroll then the floating element is hidden/clipped by that overflow setting. I'd like the floating element, in this instance, to be attached outside of this DOM structure, so that it's not affected by the overflow setting. Material UI (mat-select) does this.

I have the code below, and I would expect that the detectOverflow middleware to be attaching my floating-ui element to the body, but it doesn't.

```
        computePosition(triggerElement, popperElement, {
            placement: 'bottom',
            middleware: [
                flip(),
                {
                    name: 'middleware',
                    async fn(state) {
                        const overflow = await detectOverflow(state, {
                            boundary: document.querySelector('body')
                        });
                        return {};
                    }
                }
            ]
        }).then(({ x, y }) => {
            Object.assign(optionsElement.style, {
                left: `${x}px`,
                top: `${y}px`
            });
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a ping to their github site, I was given back the following code which does return what I want and can then use it:

```
const middlewareDO = {
  name: "mything",
  async fn(state) {
    const overflow = await detectOverflow(state, {
      boundary: body,
    });
    return {
      data: {
        shouldFlip: overflow.top >= 0,
      }
    };
  },
};
```

Note the `data:` portion, that was not in the docs and still is not.

In my case, `body` is an element I want it to clip on, not the actual page body.

You can then access it via the `middlewareData.mything.shouldFlip` when you pass the other 2 parameters to it, `placement, middlewareData`:

```
.then(({ x, y, placement, middlewareData }) => {
  Object.assign(popover.style, {
    left: `${x}px`,
    top: `${y}px`,
  });

  const { x: arrowX, y: arrowY } = middlewareData.arrow;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Since asking the above I found a library that does this for me (melt-ui), but I thank you on behalf of anyone looking for this answer.